# How do we specify the expiry date of a certificate when creating the public key via openssl command

Tags: openssl

I am generating a private and public key using the below command.

openssl genrsa -out private.pem 2048

openssl rsa -in private.pem -outform PEM -pubout -out public.pem

But I am unable to add the expiry date here, how to add the expiry data to the public key here.

Answer (score 18):

Your getting confused between a [RSA private/public key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) and a [x509 certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509).

The RSA private/public key don't have dates in them so they don't expire.  RSA Private/Public keys are used for [asymmetric cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) operations.

X509 certificates uses a private key to "sign" the certificate so that the corresponding public key can be used to verify the data in the certificate hasn't been modified.

When you create a certificate you normally create a certificate "request" that is sent to a CA to generate the certificate and sent back to you.  The expire date is normally requested as a number of days in the certificate request.  The CA can override this value to what if wants to allow, so you may not get the date you want but what the CA will allow you to have.

If you use openssl to generate the certificate request you use the [openssl req](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-req.html) command.  You use the "-days" parameter to specify expire days from time of certificate generation.

If you just want to generate a self signed certificate, you use the openssl req command with the "-x509" parameter.  Again you can use the "-days" parameter to specify expire days.

Comment: does ECDSA public key has expiry date?

Comment: The answer above also applies to EC algorithms as well.  So No a ECDSA public key does not have a expiry date, but a X509 ECDSA certificate based on the ECDSA public key will have a expiry date.  The private/public keys are just raw data for the algorithm types.

Comment: Is it applies to ECDSA signatures as well?

Comment: Yes it does.  A x509 certificate contains a body and a signature.  The body contains a date range (start and end dates) and the public key.  The body can be verified that it hasn't changed using the public key to verify the signature.  The application using the certificate is then responsible to check that the certificate is valid to use (e.g. within the date range).  The application if it wants to can ignore the date range if it wishes or any of the certificate requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding more information to [shane's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60955988).

Copied from https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-req.html

```
-days n

    When the -x509 option is being used this specifies the number of days to certify the certificate for, otherwise it is ignored. n should be a positive integer. The default is 30 days.
```

**-days** only works with **-x509** . If using **-x509** then default is **30 days**.

While generating private and public pem file, **-days** will get ignored.